# Regex for field and variable

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match fields in a Java class using regex. So far it's been working great overall, but with just one issue. Once I match a field, I then have a second regex for matching the name of the field. I use `(\w+)\s*(?:\s*=\s*[^;,]+)?` to match the name of fields, but if the value of the field is wrapped in brackets with spaces separating values for that field, it starts matching field values as field names. For example, the below matches all the names called value#, however, once it gets to value5, the 2 is matched because of the space inside the brackets separating the field's value. I need a way to not match spaces while inside brackets, if possible, while still accomplishing what is currently matched with values 1-4. Even a solution that can match value 5 properly but will mess up with 6 and 7 would be a welcomed improvement.

Sample code:

```
value1;
value2 = 3;
value3 = 4, value4 = 4;
value5 = {
    1, 2
};
value6 = {
    1, 2
}, value7 = {
    1, 2
};
```

Comment: Regular expressions are not really powerful enough to parse complex programming languages like this, you generally need to write a recursive-descent parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([a-zA-Z_]\w*)(?:\s*=\s*(?:\{[^\}]+\}|[\{;,]+))?
```

This expression also takes advantage of the fact that field names cannot begin with a digit.